# How can I combine two SQL queries to show result in one table when there is inheritance

Tags: sql, spring-data-jpa

I have the following structure User is a parent to Assignee and Submitter.  A Submitter has a one to many relationship with Request.  A Request is Many to Many relationship with Assignee.

I have the following 2 queries that I'd like to combine into one table:

```
Select r.request_number, u.first_name as Assignee
from requests r, users u
join request_assignee ra on r.id = ra.request_id
join assignee a on u.id = ra.assignee_id;

Select requests.request_number as Request_Number, users.first_name as Submitter
from requests
Join submitter on requests.submitter_id = submitter.id
Join request_assignee on requests.id = request_assignee.request_id
join users on submitter.id = users.id;
```

There can be more than one assignee to the request. How can I do 1 query to display results in one table?

Here is a picture that might help with the tables:

[image: schema]

Comment: Could you please elaborate the cross join between requests and users in first query? Also what's the expected output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assumption: Output `Request Number`, `Submitter`, `Assignee`.

The query could be simplified as below. The reason is `ASSIGNEE` and `SUBMITTER` are not required. `USERS` with alias for two different roles should be good enough.

```
select r.request_number,
       s.first_name as submitter,
       a.first_name as assignee
  from requests r
  join request_assignee ra
    on r.id = ra.reqeust_id
  join users s
    on r.submitter_id = s.id
  join users a
    on ra.assignee_id = a.id;
```

Current data model: `SUBMITTER` and `ASSIGNEE` do not provide additional information. `ID` column is redundant.

[image]

Suggested data model by removing `SUBMITTER` and `ASSIGNEE` table.

[image]

Comment: Users will have up to three different roles they can be an assignee, submitter, or "client." Each one has a different relationship mapping, separating them was easier to manage the relationships.  Initially, I had them as separate classes but the information stored for now was the same, and inheritance seemed to be the best option. Still very new to this, also your query above solved my issue, can you tell me a methodology you follow to do this, seems so easy when reading it, but I spent a few hours yesterday not being able to accomplish the query.

Comment: @Altaf Not sure there's methodology for this. I'm following "Abstraction Principle" to look at the question and asking myself like: what's the difference? what's in common?  which leads to a more generic approach.

Answer (score 0):

maybe，change the column name and keep them uniform, and try this

```
Select r.request_number as Request_Number, u.first_name as Submitter
from requests r, users u
join request_assignee ra on r.id = ra.request_id
join assignee a on u.id = ra.assignee_id
unionall 
Select requests.request_number as Request_Number, users.first_name as Submitter
from requests
Join submitter on requests.submitter_id = submitter.id
Join request_assignee on requests.id = request_assignee.request_id
join users on submitter.id = users.id
```